# If I navigate with Router.push() in next.js, I get: TypeError: products.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js, redux-saga

I am using redux saga in the project. here is the state:

const productList = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.productList);
const { loading, error, products, page, pages } = productList;

I dispatch `fetchProductsStart` in useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchProductsStart());
    if (!userInfo?.isAdmin) {
      Router.push("/login");
    }
  }, [dispatch, userInfo]);
```

This is how I render the products:

```
      {products &&
              products.map((product) => (
                <tr key={product.id}>
                  <td>{product.id}</td>
                  <td>{product.name}</td>
                  <td>${product.price}</td>
                  <td>{product.category}</td>
                  <td>{product.brand}</td>
                  <td>
                    <Link href={`/admin/product/edit/${product.id}`}>
                      <Button variant="light" className="btn-sm">
                        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faEdit}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                      </Button>
                    </Link>
                    <Button
                      variant="danger"
                      className="btn-sm"
                      onClick={() => deleteHandler(product.id)}
                    >
                      <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faTrash}></FontAwesomeIcon>
                    </Button>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
```

Thsi works if I visit page manually. "admin/productlist". How ever When i click edit button, I m redirected to "admin/product/edit/[id]" and when I click on update button I programmically navigated to "admin/productlist" I m getting "TypeError: products.map is not a function". I navigate inside saga function:

```js
function* productUpdateAsync(action: IProductUpdateStart) {
  try {
    const getState = (state: RootState) => state.user;
    const { userInfo } = yield select(getState);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json",
        Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}`,
      },
    };
    const { data } = yield axios.put(
      `${process.env.DJANGO_API_URL!}/api/products/update/${
        action.payload.id
      }/`,
      action.payload.data,
      config
    );
    yield put(productUpdateSuccess(data));
    Router.push(`${process.env.BASE_URL}/admin/productlist`);
  } catch (e) {
    yield put(productUpdateFailure(e.message));
  }
}
```

I dont understand why page is throwing error If I am programmicatly navigated.

Answer (score 0):

check the composition of your **{ data }** object which you get back from the Axios.put() request. I assume youre supposed to get back an updated **Product** and your <productUpdateSuccess(data)> function is supposed to be updating the Array of **Products**. Are you sure you're not overriding the **Products** Array in your state with another data type? **map()** function only exists as **Array.prototype.map()**